# Return parameter values sent through pthread_create while calling another function

Tags: c, multithreading

Is it possible to pass parameters to the function called by `pthread_create` and also get some values returned from this function? 
For example:

```
pthread_create(&pthread, NULL, function_call, (void*) numb1);
```

I am calling `function_call` but I want to pass multiple parameters to it except only one (`numb1`), and then I need the new updated values (updates done inside `function_call`) to be returned to `main` (where `function_call` is called).

Comment: malloc a struct that has fields for all the parameters, results, error-messages etc that the thread may need to use.  Use its address as your pointer arg.  How you signal it back to main(), or wherever, is up to you and your overall design.

Comment: ...but, one flexible option is to add a function pointer parameter to the struct that the thread will call with the struct pointer as a parameter.  That would allow the thread that raised the struct to set a function that will be called when the thread had finished its work.  That function could do whatever the user wants - post the struct ptr to a producer-consumer queue, message it to a GUI, terminate the thread so that join() gets signaled, (if you really must), whatever:)

Comment: @MartinJames from what i understood from yous solution this explains how i send multiple parameters in the function. Lets say i will use a structure, this I have already done it.. But how do i get the values of these parameters back in main, after function_call is called?